# Python Login to UPS.com returns 403

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I had a script that would login to my UPS.com account to receive all incoming packages. The following code was working for a while but not anymore:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
url = "https://www.ups.com/lasso/login?loc=en_US&returnto=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2Fus%2Fen%2FHome.page"
headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
  'Referer': 'https://www.ups.com/us/en/services/tracking/mychoice.page',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
response = s.get(url, headers=headers, data = payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
# Get CSRF Token
token = soup.find(id='CSRFToken').get('value')

# Now login
url = "https://www.ups.com/lasso/login"

payload = "CSRFToken={}&loc=null&returnto=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ups.com%252Fupsmychoice%253Floc%253Den_US&forgotpassword=YZ&connectWithSocial=YZ&userID=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&rememberMe=1&getTokenWithPassword=&ioBlackBox=&ioElapsedTime=5026".format(token)
headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Origin': 'https://www.ups.com',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
  'Referer': 'https://www.ups.com/lasso/login?loc=en_US&returnto=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ups.com%2Fus%2Fen%2Fservices%2Ftracking%2Fmychoice.page',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

response = s.post(url, headers=headers, data = payload)
```

This now returns a 403 with message "You don't have permission to access ... on this server"

I used Selenium webdriver on the same server to login and this worked when I filled out the form information with my credentials. However I am looking for a solution that only uses `requests` module.

I have even tried copying the login request directly to Postman and I received the same 403 (even when I manually updated `CSRFToken`)

What can I do to login via requests to ups.com?

Comment: Are you still able to log in just fine using a regular browser? You're sure you aren't blocked or banned or something?

Comment: Yeah logging in normally works. Even logging in via Selenium Webdriver on that server works.

Comment: I guess at this point if I were you I'd open the browser dev tools, clear your cache and cookies, then log in while capturing network traffic. Then see if there's anything extra happening before or after that request. My thought is that there's some kind of script running in addition to that request, which `requests` wouldn't be aware of, and it's doing some kind of additional authentication.

Comment: If you copy the cookie from the dev tool and use it in the header, you should get the response you need.

Comment: @SIM Yes you are correct using the cookies will work. But I am sure these will expire after some time. Is there a way to use requests to get the cookie values?

Comment: had the exact same issue - my script just stopped working and I can't figure out why

Comment: @Arthur They must be generating some kind of token in cookies and checking for it on certain requests. I ended up using selenium webdriver to create headless window, login, getting the cookies, and saving it to a `requests` Session object.

Comment: Hey @Bijan is this method still working?

Comment: @degemenc No, I had to make some changes. Now I am using the `undetected-chromedriver` in headless mode and just intercept the request that returns the package list in JSON format.